# Как удалить из базы MySQL похожие записи?

Tags: php, mysqli

Есть столбцы: id, и artist, и похожие записи например:

1. Руки Вверх,
2. **гр**. Руки Вверх,

или

3. Алла Пугачева,
4. А. Пугачева.

Как удалить 2ю, и 4ю записи, но при этом чтобы остались 1я, и 3я?

Comment: Надо определить признак "похожести", по какому удалять
В Вашем примере этот признак выделить сложно

Comment: эта задача НЕ для MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Простого решения данного вопроса нет и так или иначе вам придется выполнить часть работы вручную. Если бы подобную задачу пришлось решать мне:

1. Необходимо "скормить" поле artist какому либо поисковому движку (например [sphinxsearch](http://sphinxsearch.com/)).
2. Выбрать несколько полей для эксперимента и настроить поисковик наиболее оптимальным способом. (для этого придется поиграть с его настройками достаточно долго особенно когда вы делаете это первый раз).
3. Выбирать из базы данных строки по одному и скармливать их поисковику. Если 2 пункт сделан правильно, то поисковик достаточно уверенно определит схожесть ваших примеров.
4. Выполнив предыдущие пункты у вас будет набор полей, которые, ВНИМАНИЕ, **возможно**, являются копиями и их можно удалить. Я бы рекомендовал результаты подобного поиска просматривать вручную перед удалением.